# Add Oracle leading hint to HQL query

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, oracle11g, hql

i want to add Leading hint to my hql query but , this hints will be like this leading(a alias name), in hibernate i dont know what the alias will be in sql , how can i do this ?

```
 String hql="select s.id from " + StoreHouseInventoryItem.class.getName() + "s ,"+ Storehouse.class.getName() +" ss "
```

i want to add leading hint to this query and i don't know hibernate aliases for these 2 table , and leading needs alias .

hibernate will generate sql like this :

```
select storeHouse0_.id  from app_item storeHouse0_ 
, app_str storeHouse1_
```

Comment: its a bit undlear what your asking for. can you elaborate more

Comment: I edit the question

Comment: It is worth mentioning that the hint should be a temporary work-round while you work out what is making the Oracle optimizer NOT do what you want in the first place. If stats on the table change then Oracle can not adapt your query to the new 'demographic' as easily if you have the hint.

Answer (score 2):

String concatenation is a very serious issue which can lead to [SQL Injection attacks](https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-sql-injection-and-how-you-should-prevent-it/).

So, because you need to vary the entity type, you need to use Criteria API which allows you to pass SQL Hints using the `org.hibernate.comment` Query Hint, like this:

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery();
Root employee = criteriaQuery.from(StoreHouseInventoryItem.class);
Root address = criteriaQuery.from(Storehouse.class);
criteriaQuery.multiselect(employee, address);
Query query = entityManager
    .createQuery( criteriaQuery)
    .unwrap( org.hibernate.query.Query.class )
    .setComment( "leading(storehouseinventoryitem0_, storehouse1_)" );
List<Object[]> result = query.getResultList();
```

And you also have to enable SQL-level hints:

```
<property
    name="hibernate.use_sql_comments"
    value="true"
/>
```

### Update

As for knowing the aliases, you just run the query and find out what aliases Hibernate has assigned for each entity, and then you should use those in the Oracle Hint.

Comment: how do you know the aliases will be storehouseinvetpryitem0_,storehous1_ ??

Answer (score 0):

I did the following and it worked for me:

1. Created a interceptor class

   ```
   public class HibernateEntityInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor {

       private static final String HINT_START = "'$HINT-";
       private static final String HINT_END = "-$HINT',";
       private static final String ORACLE_HINT_START = "/*+ ";
       private static final String ORACLE_HINT_END = " */ ";

       @Override
       public String onPrepareStatement(String sql) {

           if (sql.contains(HINT_START)) {
               String hintText = StringUtils.substringBetween(sql, HINT_START, HINT_END);
               sql = StringUtils.replace(sql, HINT_START + hintText + HINT_END, ORACLE_HINT_START + hintText + ORACLE_HINT_END);
           }
           return sql;
       }

       public static String hint(String hint, boolean isEnabled) {
           return isEnabled ? HINT_START + hint + HINT_END : "";
       }
   }
   ```
2. Used it in HQL like below. Here I am using "HASH_SJ" oracle hint.

   ```
   String hql = "select " + HibernateEntityInterceptor.hint("HASH_SJ", true) + " 1 from tableEntityA";
   ```
3. Registered the interceptor

   ```
   jpaProperties.setProperty("hibernate.ejb.interceptor", "com.abc.HibernateEntityInterceptor");
   ```